# IONIC ERRO: ionic cordova build android

Tags: android, ionic, apk

```
(node:8160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\lusan\PhpstormProjects\pwlc\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\synconset\ImageFetcher.java:293: error: Entry is not public in LinkedHashMap; cannot be accessed from outside package
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry<Integer, Bitmap> eldest) {
                                                         ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\lusan\PhpstormProjects\pwlc\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\synconset\MultiImageChooserActivity.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s (node:8160) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit cod e.

Comment: Poderia colocar mais informações? Código que está testando, ambiente utilizado, etc.

Comment: coloquei como resposta

Comment: Você pode [edit] sua pergunta para adicionar as informações, a área de respostas não é para ser utilizada para outras funções

Answer (score 0):

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.9.4
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```